# How merge osm files with same ID objects?

Tags: openstreetmap, merge

How merge many OSM files with same ID(between files) to one OSM file? I trying OSMCONVERT but he not add object with same ID in other OSM file.

Answer (score 2):

osmconvert, according to [the OSM wiki](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmconvert#Updating_OSM_Files), supports only *change* files (.osc or .o5c) but can't merge regular .osm files.

You can use [osmium](http://osmcode.org/osmium-tool/) for merging:

`osmium merge file1.osm file2.osm -o merged.osm`.

Or alternatively [osmosis](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis):

```
osmosis --rx 1.osm --rx 2.osm --rx 3.osm --merge --merge --wx merged.osm
```

Note that for *n* files you will need *n-1* merge commands.

However you should keep in mind that merging files from different dates might not work as expected and can lead to conflicts. I don't know how good these tools can handle this, if at all.

Comment: error: " Node -24 does not have a version attribute as OSM 0.6 are required to have.  Is this a 0.5 file?" JOSM saving files without version attribute in new object.

Comment: That's true. JOSM can't assign a version to a new element. This is done by the main API when uploading the file to the database. I guess you have to add fake versions to your new elements.

Comment: How add fake version by automatic?

Comment: I don't know of any existing tool capable of adding fake versions, although there should be other people that run into the same problem in the past. I guess you can add fake versions yourself with a little script in you favorite scripting language.

Comment: Yes, but i can create little script for set random ID in osm files for OSMCONVERT. :)

Comment: Why should you do that? Then you will end up with duplicated objects after merging.

Comment: I get result from osmosis and he working how osmconvert(delete same IDs).

Comment: I have't duplicate: i have osm files with same IDs, but diffirent data.

Comment: That sounds very odd. Same IDs usually refer to the same object as long as the element type (node, way, relation) matches.

Comment: Yes, but this objects not from osm DB, this objects from local PC(JOSM) and PC(JOSM) is few and saving only local and each JOSM save with own IDs - this main problem.