# How to merge OSM files with same ID?

Tags: openstreetmap, osm2pgsql, osmosis, phyghtmap, osmium

After read this [How merge osm files with same ID objects?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/152065/how-merge-osm-files-with-same-id-objects) I can't get any conclusion so please don't flag as duplicate.

I have some PBF files came from NASA SRTM ( http://katze.tfiu.de/projects/phyghtmap/phyghtmap.1.html )

My problem is phyghtmap have its own ID numbers and I believe start from same number in every PBF file.

I need to import these PBF files to my database (appart from OSM tables so official OSM ID is not a problem) using osm2pgsql.

For each HGT file I have a PBF and its own ID range that will conflict with the next files and override previous data in database.

How can I import all these files incrementing the ID for every file?

Tools I have: osmosis, osm2pgsql, osmium and phyghtmap.

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do with the data? I don't have a solution for the ID issue (except maybe writing a plugin for osmosis), but maybe there is a better way to combine your SRTM data? Do you have GDAL/OGR?

Comment: To create a layer in my Geoserver with level contours... The source is the SRTM DEM files (GeoTIFF) came in tiles. The `phyghtmap` program convert HGT to PBF and then I use osm2pgsql to import them to my database.

Comment: About `GDAL/OGR` : Tell me what you have in mind and I'll try to do it.

Comment: Already tried `osmium merge --verbose *.osm.pbf -o merged.osm.pbf --overwrite` but seems does not work. All PBF are sorted.

Comment: @BradHards are you the dev of `osmium`, `osmosis` or `osm2pgsql` ? Can I suggest a kind of `--re-index` parameter to create new `osm_id` based on the "max" ID in database? For `osm2pgsql` we have `--create` (truncate and insert new data) and `--append` (update and insert new if not exists). We need something to renumber the new ID to avoid conflict (not edit, update or override but `force append`). Same for `osmium` when `merging`.

Comment: Wait a moment.... I can try to merge the HGT files instead the PBF ...

Comment: I'm not the dev of any of them. I'd personally not ingest the PBF, but rather import the source DEM into geoserver (not postgis, but as a file) and then use the `gs:contour` WPS to generate them on the fly when needed.

Comment: Yes, I'm using it in two ways: one to convert it to contour levels (data) and other to use it as hillshading (the GeoTIFF). I can get a nice effect like www.opencyclemap.org

Answer (score 1):

Solved by merging all HGT into a single TIFF and then convert it to PBF.